# How to check the element cross the top / bottom of the window screen / viewport?

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, offset, scrolltop

## How to check element cross window screen by:

- Cross Top - from Up scrolling
- Cross Top - from Down scrolling
- Cross Bottom - from Up scrolling
- Cross Bottom - from Down scrolling

**Any solution?**

Comment: What is the question???

Comment: Hay. It's solution. Can I remove it? I just want to share this solution.

Comment: You could ask a question and answer it yourself using your solution so that'd fit this website format (Q&A)

Comment: Okay, I'll share the solution of my question. to fit in this website format (Q/A).

Answer (score 1):

***/* Crossed - TOP - from - UP Scrolling */***

```
if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= jQuery('#ELEMENT').offset().top ) {
    console.log('Crossed top - from up scroll');
}
```

***/* Crossed - TOP - from - DOWN Scrolling */***

```
if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= jQuery('#ELEMENT').offset().top ) {
    console.log('Crossed top - from down scroll');
}
```

***/* Crossed - BOTTOM - from - DOWN Scrolling */***

```
if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= jQuery('#ELEMENT').offset().top + jQuery('#ELEMENT').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
    console.log('crossed bottom from - down scroll');
}
```

***/* Crossed - BOTTOM - from - UP Scrolling */***

```
if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= jQuery('#ELEMENT').offset().top + jQuery('#ELEMENT').outerHeight() ) {
    console.log('crossed bottom from - up scroll');
}
```